# Glass Camera Bitmap Data

Tags: android, bitmap, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm writing a GDK app that listens for the camera to take a photo and upload it to service. It looks like I'm only getting returned the file path for the image rather then the bitmap data. Saving the file to the file system is taking about 5 seconds (down from 10 seconds with the new XE11). But the intent resolves much faster. Can I get access to the bitmap data before it is saved to the file system?

```
if ((android.os.Build.PRODUCT).equals("google_sdk")) {
    // Emulator
    mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
}
else if ((android.os.Build.PRODUCT).equals("glass_1")) {
    // Glass
    String filePath = (String) extras.get("picture_file_path");
    File imageFile = new File(filePath);
    // Pull bitmap from image file
    mImageBitmap = ...;
}
// Do stuff with bitmap
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to processing that happens on Glass when the picture is taken, the file may not be immediately available when `onActivityResult` is called.

See the [Javadoc for the Glass `Camera` class](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/media/Camera) for more information. The recommended approach is to use a `FileObserver` to observe the parent directory of the picture file path for a `CLOSE_WRITE` event on the file, at which point you will know that the picture is ready.